# Jquery - Get value of checkbox inside li on span click

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is list inside ul li like below:

```
    <ul class="AllLayer">
    <li>
        <fieldset id="layer0">
            <label class="checkbox" for="visible0">
                <input id="visible0" class="visible" type="checkbox" /> OSM
            </label>
            <span class="edit fa fa-pencil-square">eidt</span>
        </fieldset>
    </li>
    <li>
        <fieldset id="layer1">
            <label class="checkbox" for="visible1">
                <input id="visible1" class="visible" type="checkbox" value="osm2" /> osm2
            </label>
            <span class="edit fa fa-pencil-square">eidt</span>
        </fieldset>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When user click on span I must get value of checkbox before this span.
I wrote below code but it return `undefined`.

```
$("span.edit").on('click', function () {
    var value= (this).parent().siblings("input[type='checkbox']").attr("value");
    alert(value);
});
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method to get the checkbox inside its parent.

Additionally, you can use [`:checkbox`](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector to get checkbox element which would be better than the [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and the value can be access using [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method.

```js
$("span.edit").on('click', function() {
  var value = $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").val();
  // or $(this).sblings().find(":checkbox").val()
  // or $(this).prev().find(":checkbox").val()
  alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="AllLayer">
  <li>
    <fieldset id="layer0">
      <label class="checkbox" for="visible0">
                <input id="visible0" class="visible" type="checkbox" /> OSM
            </label>
      <span class="edit fa fa-pencil-square">eidt</span>
    </fieldset>
  </li>
  <li>
    <fieldset id="layer1">
      <label class="checkbox" for="visible1">
                <input id="visible1" class="visible" type="checkbox" value="osm2" /> osm2
            </label>
      <span class="edit fa fa-pencil-square">eidt</span>
    </fieldset>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Pranac C Balan, Thank you.

Comment: @Farzaneh : glad to help you :)