# Find Selector for Checkbox's Input Inside UL & LI at Form for jQuery

Tags: jquery

1st question, I create a filter form, and when click on li children (just child class no li parent) then check if checkbox is checked.

```
<form action='https://intrastro.com/location/' method='post' class='searchandfilter' id='search-filter-form-11' autocomplete='off' data-instance-count='1'>
<ul>
    <li class="sf-field-taxonomy-region" data-sf-field-name="_sft_region" data-sf-field-type="taxonomy" data-sf-field-input-type="radio">
        <ul class="">
            <li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0 sf-option-active" class="sf-input-radio" type="radio" value="" name="_sft_region[]" checked="checked" id="sf-input-bc44f56e7d5565fa72a5f8502685316c">
                <label class="sf-label-radio" for="sf-input-bc44f56e7d5565fa72a5f8502685316c">All Regions</label>
            </li>
            <li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-2" data-sf-count="4" data-sf-depth="0"><input  class="sf-input-radio" type="radio" value="mumbai" name="_sft_region[]" id="sf-input-2483c4a7542a7c52782a6c8b307c3497">
                <label class="sf-label-radio" for="sf-input-2483c4a7542a7c52782a6c8b307c3497">Mumbai</label>
            </li>
            <li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-3" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0"><input  class="sf-input-radio" type="radio" value="pune" name="_sft_region[]" id="sf-input-b17ab188cddb5b1c9882ea5af2f5294b">
                <label class="sf-label-radio" for="sf-input-b17ab188cddb5b1c9882ea5af2f5294b">Pune</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sf-field-taxonomy-region" data-sf-field-name="_sft_region" data-sf-field-type="taxonomy" data-sf-field-input-type="select">
        <h4>Filter on the basis of your location</h4>
        <label>
            <select name="_sft_region[]" class="sf-input-select" title="">
                <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0 sf-option-active" selected="selected" data-sf-count="0" data-sf-depth="0" value="">Select Location</option>
                <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-4" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="altamont-road">Altamont Road</option>
                <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-5" data-sf-count="2" data-sf-depth="0" value="andheri">Andheri</option>
                <option class="sf-level-0 sf-item-6" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0" value="bandra">Bandra</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I try this but no given alert:

```
<script>
(function($)
{
    $('input[name=_sft_region]:checked', '#search-filter-form-11').click(function()
    {
            alert("Checked!");
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

2nd question, how to get jquery selector by using web developer tools for chrome or firefox?

Comment: Share your `html` also, That will help everyone to understand

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45519505/jquery-get-value-of-checkbox-inside-li-on-span-click)